# how to reduce the time taken to populate tree node in asp.net c# treeview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am binding the XML Data to treeview using XMLDataSource. Its working fime, but when the Number of nodes and childnodes increases, the treenode expand and to display the content in
iframe takes moer time.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1"  OnSelectedNodeChanged = "OnClick" runat="server" 
                    ExpandDepth="0"  ShowExpandCollapse="true" ForeColor="Red" Font-Underline = "false" 
                    ondatabinding="TreeView1_DataBinding" CollapseImageUrl = "Resources/TocColapse.bmp" ExpandImageUrl = "Resources/TocParent.bmp" Font-Names="Arial"   >
                    <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="false" BackColor="White" ForeColor="#0483e0" />
                    <NodeStyle Font-Size="11pt" ForeColor="white" HorizontalPadding="5px"
                        NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" Font-Underline = "false" />
                    <ParentNodeStyle ForeColor="#0483e0" Font-Underline = "false" />
                    <LeafNodeStyle ForeColor="#0483e0" Font-Underline = "false" ImageUrl = "Resources/TocChild.bmp"  />

                </asp:TreeView>
                <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" XPath="/*/*" EnableCaching = "false" ></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

In OnDataBinding event of treeview I implemented the following code:

```
 TreeNodeBinding[] TreeNode = new TreeNodeBinding[Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            TreeNode[i] = new TreeNodeBinding();
            TreeNode[i].DataMember = TableOfContents[i].GetElementName();
            TreeNode[i].TextField = TableOfContents[i].GetFirstAttributeName();
            TreeNode[i].ValueField = TableOfContents[i].GetSecondAttributeName();
            // TreeNode[i].Target = "contentFrame";
            TreeView1.DataBindings.Add(TreeNode[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it does. Take a look towards lazy loading.

Comment: if i use the OnItemPopulate and populateOndemand = true. Is it possible to use the XMLDatasource ?

Comment: http://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/TreeView-ASP-NET-Populate-OnDemand-AID409.aspx

Comment: i read this tutorial according that i modified the my code.. But it wont fire the OntreeItempopulate method... Will you modified my code according lazy binding

Answer (score 0):

What about setting EnableCaching to "true"?

Also, are you sure that you need to display the whole xml? You could provide the user some filtering which reduces the size of the displayed xml.

Comment: if i set EnableCaching to "true" or false doesnot make any difference.

Comment: is it possible to do using the PopulateOndemand flag .. But i did not get how to use PopulateOndemand  with the XMLDatasource and treeview

Comment: i provided the single expand feature  to tree view. Only one node will populate..

Answer (score 0):

Try for populate on demand.

I used populate on demand when it was taking so long time in loading the treeview in the client side.